# Sencha Touch Google Maps marker listener not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sencha-touch

I'm having an issue with listeners on Google Maps.

```
var marker_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/map/' + thisIcon + '.png', new google.maps.Size(32, 32));        var trafficMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(alert.lat, alert.lon),
        map: trafficMap,
        icon: marker_icon,
        id: 'trafficAlertIcon' + i
    });
    console.log('Test Log3');

    google.maps.Event.addListener(trafficMarker, 'mousedown', function() 
    {
        console.log('touched marker');
        trafficTabPanel.layout.setActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
        LoadIncidentMap(this.id.substring(16));
    });
```

There seems to be an issue with the listener as it is not hitting the console.log('touched marker');.

I've tried changing the listener to trafficMap to see if that responds but it does not. I have tried, click, mousedown, mouseup etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the current version of Sencha Touch.

There is a fix here:- [Maps Listener on click](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129126-Google-Maps-Listener-on-click).

Just add the following code before initiating maps:

```
Ext.gesture.Manager.onMouseEventOld = Ext.gesture.Manager.onMouseEvent;
Ext.gesture.Manager.onMouseEvent = function(e) {
var target = e.target;

while (target) {
    if (Ext.fly(target) && Ext.fly(target).hasCls('x-map')) {
        return;
    }

    target = target.parentNode;
}

this.onMouseEventOld.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`google.maps.event`

not

`google.maps.Event`